# Fastest algorithm to calculate the number of business days between two dates?

Tags: algorithm, scala, jodatime

I have stumbled upon this problem couple of times before and there are some SO answers around but they are extremely slow e.g.

```
def businessDaysBetween(startDate: DateTime, endDate: DateTime): Seq[DateTime] = {
    1 to daysBetween(startDate, endDate) map {
      startDate.withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.days(), _)
    } diff holidays filter {
      _.getDayOfWeek() match {
        case DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY | DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY => false
        case _ => true
      }
    }
}

def daysBetween(startDate: DateTime, endDate: DateTime) = 
    Days.daysBetween(startDate.toDateMidnight(), endDate.toDateMidnight()).getDays()
```

My question is not only how to compute the number of business days between two dates but also the fastest possible solution. Note that I only need to know the number of business days and not the actual dates.

Comment: Depending on your use-case, pre-compute it and just look it up (we actually did this for days left in year at one company - we were using Lotus Notes and it was too painful to contemplate doing it on the fly)

Comment: Why would you precompute and cache something that can be done in constant time? 

Comment: Because, depending on your use case, it might be faster. Especially if your implementation language is slow at calculating it.

Comment: And it makes it easier if the requirement is actually working days (i.e. Excluding public holidays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly more readable version in my opinion with the same `O(C)` complexity:

```
  def getPreviousWorkDay(d: DateTime): DateTime = {
    d.withDayOfWeek(Math.min(d.getDayOfWeek, DateTimeConstants.FRIDAY)).withTimeAtStartOfDay()
  }

  def businessDaysBetween(startDate: DateTime, endDate: DateTime): Int = {
    val workDayStart = getPreviousWorkDay(startDate)
    val workDayEnd = getPreviousWorkDay(endDate)

    val daysBetween = Days.daysBetween(workDayStart, workDayEnd).getDays
    val weekendDaysBetween = daysBetween / 7 * 2
    val additionalWeekend = if(workDayStart.getDayOfWeek > workDayEnd.getDayOfWeek) 2 else 0

    daysBetween - weekendDaysBetween - additionalWeekend
  }
```

I consider that the week starts on Monday (the default for Joda).

I also consider that between a Saturday and the following Friday there are 5 business days, whereas between a Monday and the following Friday there are only 4 business days.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Weekends are made of 2 separate days and should be treated as such. SkyWalker's solution may not be as readable, but is the only correct solution for this algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

And this is I think the fastest solution, only need to consider which day of the week the `startDate` represents. The complexity is `O(C)`:

```
def businessDaysBetween(startDate: DateTime, endDate: DateTime): Int = {
    val numDays = daysBetween(startDate, endDate)
    val numHolidays: Int = startDate.getDayOfWeek match {
      case DateTimeConstants.MONDAY => (numDays / 7)*2 + (if (numDays % 7 > 4) min(numDays % 7 - 4, 2) else 0)
      case DateTimeConstants.TUESDAY => (numDays / 7)*2 + (if (numDays % 7 > 3) min(numDays % 7 - 3, 2) else 0)
      case DateTimeConstants.WEDNESDAY => (numDays / 7)*2 + (if (numDays % 7 > 2) min(numDays % 7 - 2, 2) else 0)
      case DateTimeConstants.THURSDAY => (numDays / 7)*2 + (if (numDays % 7 > 1) min(numDays % 7 - 1, 2) else 0)
      case DateTimeConstants.FRIDAY => (numDays / 7)*2 + (if (numDays % 7 > 0) min(numDays % 7, 2) else 0)
      case DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY => 1 + (numDays / 7)*2 + (if (numDays % 7 > 0) 1 else 0)
      case DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY => 1 + (numDays / 7)*2 + (if (numDays % 7 > 5) 1 else 0)
    }
    numDays - numHolidays
}
```

Comment: would you explain the math behind this formula? more of the why behind the `(numDays/7)*2...`