# Get business Work-Days between two dates excluding weekends and holiday without using Numpy and Pandas. (Only In Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

**Explanation:-**

```
import datetime

end_date = datetime.date(2021,6,30)
deadline_date = datetime.date(2021,6,23)

delta = deadline_date - end_date
days = delta.days
```

**Output :-**
`days = -7`

**Expected Ouput :-**

- 26-06-2021 - Saturday - skip this date
- 27-06-2021 - Sunday - skip this date
- 29-06-2021 - Holiday - skip this date

`expected_days = -4`

I tried the above code for getting days difference but **How to calculate days difference by excluding weekends and holiday in python?**

Comment: what is your motivation for "*without using Numpy and Pandas*"? Also, how do you define "holiday"? Those are pretty specific to where you live afaik.

Comment: 1. You need some simple database (array, list, etc.) with holidays including weekends; 2. You can loop through range of two provided dates and check if that day is holiday or not. So, then you could be able to get work days. :)

Comment: For weekends, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541944/fastest-algorithm-to-calculate-the-number-of-business-days-between-two-dates).
For holidays you will need a list or something because they have no regularity